# Python: How do I modify iterator value after some condition in 'for' loop

Tags: python

In such a loop, if the variable no is equal to 8, how can I return the 8th loop again? I couldn't do it, I'm confused.

> no -= 1 command not working

```
for no in range(0,100):
    print("No:",no)
    if no == 8:
      no -= 1 
      print("8 done return again")
```

Comment: So by "return", you don't mean "terminate the function using a `return` statement`", but rather "revert the variable to a lower value", right?

Comment: @Kevin yes i want revert the variable to a lower value.

Comment: Use a while loop. For loops in Python are all "for each" types - they don't do `i+=1` (C-style for loops `for(i=0; i<n; i++)`) at the end, they do `i=next(iterable)` (Python-style `for i in iterable`).

Comment: What is the expected result? Do you want it to get stuck on 8 forever in an infinite loop?

Comment: @kaya3 yes i want loop forever :) This is not the original code that I will use another code.

Comment: remove no -=1 and put While True: print("8 done retrun again")

Comment: Is this an XY Problem? https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/703367

Comment: If you want to loop forever on ``no == 8``, why don't you enter an actual infinite loop (i.e. ``while True:`` or ``while no == 8:``) instead? Why iterate up to ``100`` in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying the variable `no` doesn't do what you want here, because Python's `for no in range(...):` loop gets the values for `no` from the `range` iterator. That iterator doesn't know about the variable `no`, and will keep yielding the values from the range regardless of what you do to `no`.

One way to solve your problem is to use a `while` loop and explicitly control the loop variable `no` yourself. A more "Pythonic" way is to use `itertools` to construct an infinite iterator that yields the numbers

> 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8...

For example:

```py
from itertools import chain, repeat

for no in chain(range(8), repeat(8)):
    print("No:", no)
```

Keep in mind that you will still need **some** way out of the infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an infinite loop when you reach 8, then you can use this :

```
no = 0
while no < 100:
    print("No:",no)
    if no == 8:
        print("8 done return again")
    else:
        no += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This should infinitely repeat "8 done return again". By switching the if statement to a while one.

```
for no in range(0,100):
    print("No:",no)
    while (no == 8):
      print("8 done return again")
```